# How to filter on primefaces?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, filter, jsf-2

I'm using a modal window to select a value. After i make a selection and open the modal window again. I want the modal list be filtered on the selectedValue.

[image]

It goes back to the front page.
[image]

and if open modal again and select 'ABC', it should look like this:

[image]

this is look up and which list should be put in modal xhtml:

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
            xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
            xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
            xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
            xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
            xmlns:pe="http://primefaces.org/ui/extensions">


        <p:panel id="dialog-content">
            <h:form id="accountLookUpModal" style="width: 777px">

                &#xA0;
                <p:panelGrid id="Info" columns="2" columnClasses="labelColumn,fieldColumn">

                    <!-- TYPE -->
                    <h:outputLabel id="AccountType" for="accountType" value="#{message['field.type']}" />
                    <p:selectOneMenu id="accountType" rendered="#{not empty account.criteria}" value="#{account.criteria.accountType}" converter="#{enumerationConverter}" disabled="#{account.disableLookUp}">
                        <p:ajax event="change" listener="#{account.filterOnType(true)}" update="@form, :dataTableForm"/>
                        <f:selectItems itemLabelEscaped="true" value="#{enumerationBean.getaccountTypeList()}" var="c" itemLabel="#{message[c.bundleKey]}" itemValue="#{c}"/>
                    </p:selectOneMenu>

                </p:panelGrid>


            </h:form>       

            <h:form id="dataTableForm" prependId="false" style="width:777px;">

                <!-- INCLUDE Account Table -->
                <ui:include src="/includes/accountLookUp.xhtml">
                    <ui:param name="PANEL_ID"       value="accountActionPanel" />
                    <ui:param name="DT_ID"  value="accountTable" />
                    <ui:param name="DT_DATA"    value="#{account.accountTableLookUp}" />
                    <ui:param name="CR_BEAN"    value="#{accountBean}" />
                </ui:include>

            </h:form>
        </p:panel>

    </ui:composition>
```

This is the xhtml used to select the update the list:

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
        xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
        xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
        xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
        xmlns:c="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsp/jstl/core"
        xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">


    <p:dataTable id="#{DT_ID}" var="acc" emptyMessage="" value="#{DT_DATA.values}" rowIndexVar="index"
        paginator="true" selection="#{DT_DATA.selectedValues}" rows="8" paginatorPosition="top"
        paginatorTemplate="{FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"
        editable="false" lazy="true" sortBy="#{acc.name}" sortOrder="ascending"
        liveResize="true" filterDelay="100">

        <p:ajax event="filter" listener="#{DT_DATA.onFilter}"  />
        <p:ajax event="rowToggle" listener="#{account.expandLookUp(acc)}" immediate="true"/>

        <p:column styleClass="ui-column-rowtoggler" exportable="false">  
            <p:rowToggler id="cdtlu#{DT_ID}RT"/>
        </p:column>

        <!-- filterBy="#{acc.name}" -->
        <p:column id="accountName" sortBy="#{acc.name}" filterBy="#{acc.name}" >
            <f:facet name="header"> 
                <h:outputText id="cu#{DT_ID}accountName" value="#{message['field.name']}" />
            </f:facet>
            <h:outputText id="cu#{DT_ID}accountName" value="#{acc.name}"/>
        </p:column>

        <!-- filterBy="#{acc.city}" -->
        <p:column id="accountCity" sortBy="#{acc.city}" filterBy="#{acc.city}" >
            <f:facet name="header"> 
                <h:outputText id="cu#{DT_ID}accountCity" value="#{message['field.city']}" />
            </f:facet>
            <h:outputText id="cu#{DT_ID}accountCity" value="#{acc.city}" />
        </p:column>

        <!-- filterBy="#{acc.countryCode}" -->
        <p:column id="accountCountry" sortBy="#{acc.countryCode}" filterOptions="#{enumerationBean.accountList}" filterBy="countryCode"  >
            <f:facet name="header"> 
                <h:outputText id="cu#{DT_ID}CountryCode" value="#{message['field.countryCode']}" />
            </f:facet>
            <h:outputText id="cu#{DT_ID}TCountryCode" value="#{message[acc.countryCode.bundleKey]}" />
        </p:column>


        <p:column id="sel" styleClass="ui-column-rowtoggler">
            <f:facet name="header"> 
                <h:outputText id="cu#{DT_ID}Sel" value="#{message['common.sel']}" />
            </f:facet>
            <p:commandButton action="save-dialog" id="cu#{DT_ID}BtnSel"
                             actionListener="#{companySearchBean.updateCompanyOwner(acc)}"
                             icon="ui-icon ui-icon-e-w" >
            </p:commandButton>

        </p:column>


    </p:dataTable>

</ui:composition>
```

Now i would like to filter with 'name' so that it looks it last picture. I used filterValue but then filterBy doesn't work properly and it produces null. In the nutshell if I select 'ABC' and then open the modal again. it should only contain list contain name like 'ABC'.

I'm new to prime faces so any help would be appreciated. Also i apologize for terrible diagrams.

Comment: Please try to reduce this into a [MCVE]